# Serverless.yml VPC parameters

Tags: serverless-framework

I would just like to ask what are the correct format for the value in the vpc section in serverless.yml especially the securityGroupIds field and the subnetIds field. It is confusing me cause if I go to lambda service in aws console, when we add vpc settings in there the string format for securityGroupIds is something like:

`xx-xxxxxxxx(xx_xx_xxx_xxxxxx_xxxxxx)|xx_xx_xxx_xxxxx_xxxxxx`

while if I go to vpc service in aws console and click the security group, the security group id has a string format of:

`xx-xxxxxxxx | xx_xx_xxx_xxxxxx_xxxxxx`

And for subnet ids, the one in lambda page has a format like this:

`subnet-xxxxxxxx(xx.xxx.xx.0/xx)|ap-southeast-1a subnet-public-1a`

while in the vpc page the format is this:

`subnet-xxxxxxxx`

My question is which format should I enter in the serverless.yml. The on in the lambda page or the one in the vpc page?

Answer (score 1):

`vpcConfig.yml` file format should be like

```
vpcId: vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
securityGroupIds: 
  - sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
subnetId:
  - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

your lambda should have the subnet-xxxxxxxx